# Parent is Inheriting from Child - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[image: The Screenshot of browser Console]

Really confused here, checkout the image above. Why the parent a is inheriting something that i defined for its child?

Comment: Please post code, not pictures.

Comment: There is no parent, and there is no inheritance. Rather `a === b`, which explains what you're seeing.

Comment: Were you trying to do `var b = Object.create(a)`?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry about posting it as a picture. will keep that in mind for future. Your comment helped. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript when you assign an object variable  as a variable it is a reference to a single object just like arrays. so instead of being a copy of the object it is pointing to the original object in memory. this means that both a and b are pointing to the same object in memory. any action taken on one variable will effect the other since they are pointing to the same instance of the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it.